# multi column search in django using ajax

Tags: python, django

I am working on a listing in django project. The scenario is that When i click on FAQ listing page then it redirects me to the listings where i get all faq. Now i have to search using different keywords. There is total five keywords through which i can search for particular results. Code is

```
questions = Help.objects.all().filter().values('id','question','description','status','created','modified').order_by('-id')
if 'question' in ajax_data:
    #add filter for question
if 'description' in ajax_data:
    #add filter for description
if 'status' in ajax_data:
    #add filter for status
if 'created' in ajax_data:
    #add filter for created
if 'modified' in ajax_data:
    #add filter for modified
questions = Help.objects.all().filter(#add all conditions here dynamically after applying filters).values('id','question','description','status','created','modified').order_by('-id')
```

First when page refresh it executes first query which returns all data, now using ajax filters have to be applied, i have done all ajax code just want logic of this search. Search should perform like if i enter question only it should filter according to question, but if i search using question, status and created filed it should apply filter for all these three keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
questions = Help.objects.all()
filters = {}
if 'question' in ajax_data:
    filters['question'] = ajax_data.get('question')
if 'description' in ajax_data:
    filters['description'] = ajax_data.get('description')
if 'status' in ajax_data:
    filters['status'] = ajax_data.get('status')
if 'created' in ajax_data:
    filters['created'] = ajax_data.get('created')
if 'modified' in ajax_data:
    filters['modified'] = ajax_data.get('modified')
questions = questions.filter(**filters).values('id','question','description','status','created','modified').order_by('-id')
```

Check this link https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument

Comment: but in this how can i use contains or greater than less than operators

Comment: you can use like filters['created__gt'],filters['created__lt'] etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.GET.get('filter_name')`

e.g if you have a filter by title:

```
query = Model.objects.all()
title = request.GET.get('title')    
if title:
    query = query.filter(title__icontains=title)

...and so on
```

note that your url should contain get parameters like `http://myurl.com/?title=abc`

**EDIT**
    for one query filter you can use `Q` object from `django.db.models`

```
filter = Q()
if title:
    filter &= Q(title__icontains=title)
if category:
    filter &= Q(category__icontains=category)
query = query.filter(filter)
```

Comment: But this function will always execute multiple queries for keywords, like if i apply three filters then it will execute queries three times, is it not possible to create filter conditions in each if statement and finally execute query with that condition

Comment: Error global name Q is not defined

Comment: did you import Q? @Pankaj

Comment: Nice, but it is working for exact lookups not for like matches, I have also used title__icontains

Comment: post an example